# Project Euler Problem 8, in C (works for 4 digits, not for 13)

Tags: c

My code spits the correct answer when I calculate the highest multiplication of 4 numbers; however, it does not when I try to calculate 13. (I get an answer but it's incorrect).

BTW, I tried looking at solutions and didn't find something to help me figure out my exact error. I've also made sure to use unsigned long long ints just in case the number would be high, so I don't think that is the problem. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 13

int main (void)
{
    //variables declaration (ull just in case it's too big).
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    unsigned long long temp = 1;
    int count = 0;

    //here I paste the number from the question to insert it in the array.
    int arr[1000];
    printf("enter the number: \n");
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        scanf("%1d", &arr[i]);
    }

    //this loop makes sure we calculate all 1000 characters, with going over 1000.
    while (SIZE + count < 1000)
    {
        //loop to calculate the product of SIZE(4 or 13) elements.
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            temp *= arr[i+count];
        }
        //printf to test that it is working.
        printf("%temp %i: %llu\n", count+1, temp);
        
        //Saving the highest result in sum.
        if (sum < temp)
        {
            sum = temp;
        }
        //resetting and proceeding to the next number.
        temp = 1;
        count++;
    }
    //printing the highest sum.
    printf("\n\nsum: %i\n", sum);


    return 0;
}

//This works with SIZE 4 (the sum is the correct answer) however with SIZE 13 the answer is incorrect
```

Here is the number I would paste inside the scanf:

```
7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

The link to the project euler page: https://projecteuler.net/problem=8

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* thing the program does wrong (which will lead to the final result being wrong)?

Comment: You're printing an unsigned long long with %i ?

Comment: Both gcc and clang with default options report the problems as warnings when you compile the code. Until you're expert (and usually even then), compiler warnings should be read and heeded.

Comment: regarding; `printf("%temp %i: %llu\n", count+1, temp);`  The first char in the format string: `%` results in `<tab>emp ...`  Probably not what you want

Comment: @PaulHankin I didn't even notice I got warnings because of all the printing! thanks man, I'll remember to check for errors first thing next time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* at the line

```
printf("\n\nsum: %i\n", sum);
```

By passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. (`%i` expects `int`, but you passed `unsigned long long`)

It should be

```
printf("\n\nsum: %llu\n", sum);
```

Actually you are using `%llu` in `printf("%temp %i: %llu\n", count+1, temp);`, so you should also use that here.

Comment: OMG how did I miss that?! Thanks Mike! you rock! :D